# How to deployed micro-frontend architecture when you have multiple app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, micro-frontend

I have multiples apps on the micro frontend architecture. I have used `Lerna` for managing multi-package repositories in a single repo.
Here is the structure of my app.

```
packages
 - main-app
 - feature-based-apps
    - feature-01-app
    - feature-02-app
    - feature-03-app
    - feature-04-app
    - feature-05-app
    ...
 - shared-components
```

The `shared-components` used in `feature-based-apps` and `main-app`. The all `feature-based-apps` render in main-app in run-time. All packages build are separated and all need to deploy in a particular place. For development, all apps run on a particular port in the local setup, `3001`, `3002` and `3003`. I've moved all `feature-based-apps` packages build in `main-app` build folder and run the production build in the local setup. How can I archive this thing on actual production deployment?

We have deployed a single application on `Netlify`, `Vercel`, and `Github pages` but how I can deploy multiple apps in a single repo.